# C++ Range based stream

Tags: c++, c++11, io, stream

Hoping somebody has knowledge of the range based additions going into the standard. So they can point out all the things I need to add to make it compliant.

#### IterableStream.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Util
{
    
template<typename T>
class IterableStream
{
    std::istream&      stream;
    public:
        IterableStream(std::istream& stream)
            : stream(stream)
        {}
        operator std::istream&()            {return stream;}

        std::istream_iterator<T> begin()    {return std::istream_iterator<T>(stream);}
        std::istream_iterator<T> end()      {return std::istream_iterator<T>();}
};

}
```

Example usage

```
#include "IterableStream.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace TaU = ThorsAnvil::Util;
int main()
{
    std::ifstream x("plop");

    for(auto const& y: TaU::IterableStream<int>(x)) {
        std::cout << y << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like the name - it ought to be more explicit that it's an *input-only* range.

Otherwise, it looks just as a range should, with the observation that we omit the usual const iterators, as they don't make sense here.

I think you can avoid repetition of the return type:

```
std::istream_iterator<T> begin()    {return {stream};}
std::istream_iterator<T> end()      {return {};}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I would change the name to `istream_range`:

```
template<typename ValueType>
class istream_range
```

This will make it more in line with snake_case which standard uses, and is both cool sounding and descriptive. May be `ValueType` is a bit overkill, but I think that it makes it more clear clear that template parameter is for values.

---

I think that range should be copyable. Input iterators are copyable too, but people know that it gets invalidated. It is usefull when chaining/pipelining/propagating. The only addition would be making `stream` a pointer and putting some dereferences.

I'm not sure which is the latest paper, but here is the quote from  [n4128](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html):

> We’ve already decided that Ranges (not Iterables) are copyable and assignable

The paper notes that there is an `Iterable`, but the title of the post says `range`.

---

My opinion is that ranges should make user be able to do everything iterators can, but in a simpler and less verbose way. It would be core concept to keep in mind.

---

`std::istringstream` would be better for example. It is more convenient, and gives reviewers more control.